# Adding Authenticator PAM to Linux keyring

Tags: linux, android, two-factor-authentication

The (google) two-factor Authenticator project, which can be used to perform two-factor authentication (with something like the Android [Authenticator](https://f-droid.org/wiki/page/com.google.android.apps.authenticator2)) includes a PAM (pluggable authentication module) for Linux. I would like to use this for some password queries in my system sessions.

For example, it would be nice to have a password safe or keyring (say, GNOME Seahorse or [KeePassX](https://www.keepassx.org)) that was local, but required more than just a single password to unlock.

How can I modify the authentication process with this PAM to get two-factor authentication in those types of password prompts?

This is a pretty easy process when the application is PAM-aware, as detailed in [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/193248/google-authenticator-for-desktop-lightdm-or-gdm-plugin), but not easy if the application is not PAM-aware.

Comment: google authenticator works on linux, too. http://code.google.com/p/google-authenticator/

Comment: I see that there is a PAM module, but that alone is not enough, of course.

Answer (score 0):

You can build your own pam modules. Just use a sample "skeleton" for a pam module and include your own code.

You can start with this: https://github.com/beatgammit/simple-pam

Comment: This probably should have been a comment on the original question.